# mosquitto_sub command gives no respond when correct password?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to subscribe to a mosquitto server that I installed and configured with this command

```
mosquitto_sub -h myserver.myserver.myserver -p 9500 -t "test" -u "myuser" -P "my-correct-password" --capath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Where I substituted my actual values for `myserver.myserver.myserver`, `myuser` and `my-correct-password`.  When I run this command, my terminal doesn't give any response.  It doesn't even disconnect after waiting for a long time.

However, if I replace `my-correct-password` with a password I know is incorrect, I get the response `Connection Refused: not authorised.`   How come I can't subscribe to the mosquitto server with a correct password?  And how come I only get a response from the server if I supply an erroneous password?

I can't remember this being a problem in the past...I'm pretty sure I ran this command successfully in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all the available information in the question, the 2 simplest options.

1. There are no messages being published on the topic subscribed to.
2. There is an ACL in place on the broker and the user is not authorised to see messages on the topic subscribed to.

Add `-d` to the command line to see if the connection and the subscription actually complete successfully.